# Redirect from non-www to www with SSL

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have an Apache server hosting my HTML site. I have it setup currently to be SSL-enabled on `www.mysite.com`. It will also redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

However, I am having two issues:

First, I cannot figure out how to redirect:

- http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com (not the *ssl* there)

Second, the `www` redirect also doesn't occur I navigate to:

- https://example.com/

Below is the relevant portions of my `httpd.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  ServerAlias *
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # WITH 'www.'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*) [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.exampe.com
    SSLENGINE on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/signed/my.crt
    SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/pki/tls/signed/my.key.csr
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/signed/my.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to modify the above `VirtualHost` elements to include the https redirect (bullet point 1) and have the redirect enabled for the ssl-enabled, non-www form of the url (bullet point 2)?

Answer (score 0):

For first case remove the IfModule and mod_rewrite mess and add this in the non-SSL virtualhost:

```
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
```

For Second case add this in the SSL VirtualHost:

```
UseCanonicalName on
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Yeah, that `IFModule` was scary. Glad to see its not needed. For the second case, I added `UseCanonicalName on`, and `https://example.com/` is still not redirecting to `https://www.example.com/` Any ideas?